# Getting a TypeError (not a function) Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a super simple "see more.." link. I was doing it before with a button, but it didn't work very well on mobile, so I've changed it to a link, but I'm getting this error:
`jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: seeMore is not a function TypeError: seeMore is not a function`

Here's the code. I reckon it's just a stupid syntax error somewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seeMore = document.getElementById('seeMore');

    seeMore.onclick=seeMore();

    function seeMore(){
        document.getElementById('infoText').innerHTML= 'More text';
    };

    function seeLess(){
        document.getElementById('infoText').innerHTML= 'Less text';
    };
});
```

and here's the linked `seeMore` ID.

```
<a href="#" id="seeMore">See More</a>
```

What's going on here??

Comment: Name conflict. You used the same name for a `variable` and `function`.

Comment: As the error says. See more is not a function.

Comment: Plus you need to assign the function itself after renaming `seeMoreEl.onclick=seeMore` not `seeMoreEl.onclick=seeMore()`

Comment: Also, to assign a function as a handler, do not use braces beause doing so will execute the method instead of treating it as an object. Here is how to do it: `seeMore.onclick=myFunction;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same name for a property and a function and therefore its not clear what you mean.

You could rename one variable.

Also when you assign `seeMore()` with the brackets you assign the return value of the function and not the function itself. You need to remove the brackets.

You could also use the events which jquery provide to easily support all browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seeMoreElement = document.getElementById('seeMore');

    function seeMore(){
        document.getElementById('infoText').innerHTML= 'More text';
    };

    function seeLess(){
        document.getElementById('infoText').innerHTML= 'Less text';
    };

    $(seeMoreElement).click(seeMore);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! I've been looking at this code for far too long. Although, it's still not working very well on mobile. I'll work it out